# How to delete part of circle path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do I delete part of the circle path in the picture provided?. I want the red outlined part to be deleted without having the curve change. I've tried to do this by selecting the two anchor points (where the line meets the curve and the bottom of the curve but it deletes the whole arc. I want the top arc and line connected.

Thanks.

[image]

Hi,

I'm still having trouble with this. As I said I can't place the anchor point where the line already intersects as there is already an anchor there. If I select both anchor point or either one on their own with the direct selection tool it will select the whole arc. I'm not sure exactly where I'm going wrong here. Sorry.

The 3rd picture show what happens when I select the bottom anchor with the DS tool on it's own. It will select the whole arc rather than stopping at the anchor at the intersection of the line and arc. Any ideas?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Take **Add Anchor Point Tool** which is part of the Pen Tool and put an Anchor Point at the Intersection like so:

[image]

2. Select the anchor point at the end of the arc using the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow):

[image]

3. Delete it:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for the answer. I'm still having a problem though. The line intersecting the curve already has an anchor point so I can't place an anchor there. If I select the current anchor point where the line intersects the curve and the anchor point at the bottom of the curve and hit delete the entire curve deletes. Where am I going wrong?.

Comment: Don't select both when deleting. Only select the one at the bottom.

Comment: Hi Ryan, ugh still having trouble. I've edited the original question, can you take a look?.

Comment: @Eoin okay my instructions are correct. When you do step 1 to add the anchor point, select the arc first. You might even want to lock the other paths. There's no anchor point at that intersection ON the arc you're trying to fix. But when you click to add the anchor point there its finding the existing one from the horizontal path. Does this make sense? Basically: lock the horizontal path then follow my steps and I think it'll work for you.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, it worked perfect. I just needed to select the arc first. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure thing. Welcome to the community. If this answers it be sure to mark it as the Answer, helps us find the questions without answers that way.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not experimented with the pathfinder palette and the "minus front" option you may want to. You could just draw any shape over what you want to delete, select both top and bottom items and hit the minus front icon in the pathfinder panel